# Converting A Recursive Function into a Non-Recursive Function

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to convert a recursive function into a non-recursive solution in pseudocode. The reason why I'm running into problems is that the method has two recursive calls in it.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

```c
void mystery(int a, int b) {
    if (b - a > 1) {
        int mid = roundDown(a + b) / 2; 
         print mid; 
         mystery(a, mid); 
         mystery(mid + 1, b); 
     }
}
```

Comment: I assume the last line of code should be mystery(mid+1, b).

Comment: Is that a binary search? If so then check this link out: [Binary search algorithm Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texbook method to turn a recursive procedure into an iterative one is simply to replace the recursive call with
a stack and run a "do loop" until the stack is empty.

Try the following:

```
push(0, 16);     /* Prime the stack */
call mystery;
...

void mystery {
do until stackempty() {   /* iterate until stack is empty */
  pop(a, b)               /* pop and process... */
  do while (b - a >= 1) { /* run the "current" values down... */
    int mid = roundDown(a+b)/2;
    print mid;  
    push(mid+1, b);       /* push in place of recursive call */
    b = mid;
  }
}
```

The original function had two recusive calls, so why only a single stack? Ignore the requirements for
the second recursive call and you can easily see
the first recursive call (`mystery(a, mid);`) could implemented as a simple loop where `b` assumes the value of `mid`
on each iteration - nothing else needs to be "remembered". So turn it into a loop and simply push 
the parameters needed for the recusion onto a stack,
add an outer loop to run the stack down. Done.

With a bit of creative thinking, any recursive function can be turned into an iterative one using stacks.

Comment: That should probably be do while (b > a) or do until (b <= a).

Comment: @rcgldr Thanks for the comment. Flipped the UNTIL to a WHILE but left the rest of the condition the same since it reflects what was used in the original question, althought, your suggested conditional is cleaner and easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

This one seems more interesting, it will result in displaying all numbers from a to (b-1) in an order specific to the recursive function. Note that all of the "left" midpoints get printed before any "right" midpoints.

```c
void mystery (int a, int b) { 
    if (b > a) { 
         int mid = roundDown(a + b) / 2; 
         print mid; 
         mystery(a, mid); 
         mystery(mid + 1, b); 
    } 
}
```

For example, if `a = 0`, and `b = 16,` then the output is:

```
8 4 2 1 0 3 6 5 7 12 10 9 11 14 13 15
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem. It is still recursive. Definitely it prints all the numbers between a to b. Order might be important. (Although you fixed the bug :) )

Comment: To @rcgldr, I messed it up when I was typing in the pseudocode. Originally, it should have been mid-1 in the first recursive call and just mid in the second one.  I really need to find a non-recursive solution if anyone can figure it out.

Comment: If you use mid-1 combined with round down, the function will not print all the numbers from a to (b-1), some will be skipped.

Comment: Ok. I'll change it to mid and mid+1, but do you know how to do that with loops? I was thinking it would be a while loop but I wasn't certain how to play it out.

Comment: If using mid and mid+1, then the if needs to be if((b-a) >=1) to get all values from a to (b-1). It seems you'd need at least 3 more variable to replace what is being stored on the stack via recursion.

Comment: or simpler still, the if needs to be if(b > a) to get all values from a to (b-1). It doesn't seem that there's an easy way to convert this without using a stack or array. In some cases, a mathematical algorithm can be used to "restore" values to their previous instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening. You have a long rod, you are dividing it into two. Then you take these two parts and divide it into two. You do this with each sub-part until the length of that part becomes 1.

How would you do that?

Assume you have to break the rod at mid point. We will put the marks to cut in bins for further cuts. Note: each part spawns two new parts so we need 2<sup>n</sup> boxes to store sub-parts.

```
len = pow (2, b-a+1)      // +1 might not be needed
ar = int[len]             // large array will memoize my marks to cut
ar[0] = a                 // first mark
ar[1] = b                 // last mark 
start_ptr = 0             // will start from this point
end_ptr = 1               // will end to this point
new_end = end_ptr         // our end point will move for cuts

while true:                          //loop endlessly, I do not know, may there is a limit
  while start_ptr < end_ptr:         // look into bins
    i = ar[start_ptr]                //
    j = ar[start_ptr+1]              // pair-wise ends

    if j - i > 1                     // if lengthier than unit length, then add new marks
      mid = floor ( (i+j) / 2 )      // this is my mid
      print mid
      ar[++new_end] = i              // first mark   --|
      ar[++new_end] = mid - 1        // mid - 1 mark --+-- these two create one pair
      ar[++new_end] = mid + 1        // 2nd half 1st mark --|
      ar[++new_end] = j              // end mark          --+-- these two create 2nd pair 

    start_ptr = start_ptr + 2        // jump to next two ends

  if end_ptr == new_end             // if we passed to all the pairs and no new pair
    break                           // was created, we are done.
  else
    end_ptr = new_end               //else, start from sub prolem
```

PS: I haven't tried this code. This is just a pseudo code. It seems to me that it should do the job. Let me know if you try it out. It will validate my algorithm. It is basically a b-tree in an array.

Comment: The task can be solved with `O(log(b-a))` extra space, while the proposed algorithm requires `O(2^(b-a))`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I do not need to preserve the tree. Just enough space to accommodate the widest level, and overwrite the contents. Stack is a better choice as your solution shows.

Comment: With widest level we still need `O(2^(b-a))` space. The idea is to do DFS, so the only thing we store is the path from the root of the tree to the nodes, hence `O(log(b-a))`.

Comment: that changes the whole algorithm. Wouldn't DFS make this also same as Stack based algo? What you are saying is to use array as stack. What I am doing here is BFS. Unfortunately, my mechanism does not yield elements the same way OP's program, which is DFS.

Comment: You are correct, we are basically talking about DFS vs BFS. In fact, my DFS is nothing more than simulation of the real call stack with an array-like stack structure.

Answer (score 0):

This example recursively splits a range of numbers until the range is reduced to a single value. The output shows the structure of the numbers. The single values are output in order, but grouped based on the left side first split function.

```c
void split(int a, int b)
{
    int m;
    if ((b - a) < 2) {      /* if size == 1, return */
        printf(" | %2d", a);
        return;
    }
    m = (a + b) / 2;        /* else split array */
    printf("\n%2d %2d %2d", a, m, b);
    split(a, m);
    split(m, b);
}
```